# What is correct way to download once in RxSwift?

Tags: ios, swift, request, rx-swift

I have this code, but I'm not sure.

```
    NewsAPI.fetchNews(page: loadedPage.value + 1)
        .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
        .bind(onNext: { [weak self](news) in
            guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
            strongSelf.news.value = strongSelf.news.value + news
            strongSelf.loadedPage.value = strongSelf.loadedPage.value + 1
        })
        .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

Comment: What does it mean "single load"?

Comment: Download only once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your example should works fine, but here some remarks:

1. You should handle result of `NewsAPI.fetchNews(page: loadedPage.value + 1)` with `subscribe` or `drive` methods (for `Observable`/`Driver` type);
2. `strongSelf.loadedPage.value = strongSelf.loadedPage.value + 1` (and others) should be replaced by `strongSelf.loadedPage.value += 1`.

Result:

```
NewsAPI.fetchNews(page: loadedPage.value + 1)
    .observeOn(MainScheduler.asyncInstance)
    .subscribe(onNext: { [weak self] news in
        guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
        strongSelf.news.value += news
        strongSelf.loadedPage.value += 1
    })
    .disposed(by: disposeBag)
```